# python-sql script data entry

Tags: python, sql, database, function

i was trying to run a python-sql script

I have a database which is like this

```
-----------------------------
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 usern
```

and the python script to insert data into it reads

```
l = "111 222 333 444 555 666"
l = l.rstrip()
l = l.split()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Values VALUES( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,"uname")",l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4],l[5] )
```

now this doesn't work at all, and i cant figure out how to split the string and give inputs as required into the sql table

the output should come out like this

```
-----------------------------------
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 usern

111  222  333  444  555  666  uname
```

any suggestions ? i would like to run that cur.execute command in a loop later on to input multiple entries

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Can you clarify what problem you've encountered?

Comment: One problem is that you have a syntax error near "uname". Escape double quotes with `\"` or wrap the statement in single quotes. The second possible problem is that you might also use `cur.execute('begin')` and `cur.execute('commit')` to begin and commit transactions depending on what database and/or database engine you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the values you pass to the cur.execute() should be a tuple or list, and you are just passing through the values. Try this:

```
 l = "111 222 333 444 555 666" 
 #this splits and creates a list
 vals = l.split()
 sql = """INSERT INTO Values VALUES( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,\"uname\")"""
 cur.execute(sql, vals)
```